# iOS Zxing Widget wont build any more

Tags: ios, xcode, zxing

I get the following error message when i want to build my project which includes the zxing library:

```
clang: error: no such file or directory: '/Users/xxxx/Desktop/zxing-2.0/ZXingWidget_Prefix.pch'
clang: error: no input files
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang failed with exit code 1
```

It only happens since i updated xcode to 4.6

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you using static zxing library or dependent project?

If dependent project then try below steps:

1) Select project **ZXingWidget.xcodeproj**

2) Select Targets **ZXingWidget**

3) Select Build Settings tab

4) Search keyword "header".

5) Set "**Precompile Prefix Header**" field to "**Yes**".

6) Set "**Prefix Header**" field to "**ZXingWidget_Prefix.pch**".

7) Clean and build your project again.

Hope this would help!

Comment: can you please tell how to you fix it. still now i am getting clang error